# ServerAlias - Force Apache to use 301 by default instead of 302

Tags: redirect, apache-2.4, serveralias

I currently have the following in my config file:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAlias www.example.org
ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
```

This all works great because if I go to www.example.org/something I get redirected to http://example.com/something  The only problem is that the redirection that occurs is "temporary" ie: 302 instead of 301.

How can I change this so that it will be a 301 instead while still using the very popular ServerAlias command?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the 302 was generated by Apache.

You can do a 301 with something like this in your Apache configuration :

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^exemple\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What do you mean that you "don't think the 302 was generated ab Apache"? What would have generated it then.

Comment: Sadly that code above gave me a apache redirect loop

Comment: The 302 should come from your application.

Comment: It's not generated by the _core_ of apache, IOW explicitly by specifying ServerAlias. You could have mod_rewrite or Redirect stuff in your config.